# How to get value from select option dropdown and use that value in a switch statement

Tags: javascript

**WHAT WORKS**
When you enter the 'monetary' value and click the 'calculate my taxes' button, you get the correct values.

**WHAT DOESN'T WORK**
Important

The total tax you pay is also based on the duties category you select.
1. 'Electronics' is selected by default. The correct value is displayed when you calculate the tax
2. When you try to select another duty category, using the same 'total amount' the tax value displayed doesn't change.
3. Even if you refresh and use another option other than electronics, the Amount to be paid is still the same for all 3 options (based on the total amount vale you enter.)

Thanks and I appreciate your help in advance.
Here's the link to the repl: https://repl.it/@argo92/CUSTOMS-CALCULATOR

```
//Percentages based on duties category
const TAX_ELECTRONICS = 0.31 //31%
const TAX_AUTOMOBILES = 0.33 //33%
const TAX_PERISHABLES = 0.12 //12%

// Exhibit 1: Get and store value from select option
var selObj = document.getElementById("dutiesCategory");
var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;

// Check Option Value click handler
function getOption() {
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#dutiesCategory');
    output = selectElement.value;
    document.querySelector('.output').textContent = output;
}
var e = getOption();

// Exhibit 2: Test to see if we're still getting an option value
function tester() {
var f = $("#dutiesCategory").change(function() {
    var g = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    console.log(g);
});
}
tester();

// Important: I need to find a way to get the values from the select input and merge them with the calculateTax function.
function calcDutiesCatTax(val) {
    if (selValue) {
        return TAX_ELECTRONICS;
    } else if (selValue) {
        return TAX_PERISHABLES;
    } else {
        return TAX_AUTOMOBILES;
    }
};

    // function calcDutiesCatTax(val) {
    // var result = "";
    // switch (selValue === val) {
    //  case 'Electronics':
    //      result = TAX_ELECTRONICS;
    //      break;
    //  case 'Automobile':
    //      result = TAX_AUTOMOBILES;
    //      break;
    //  case 'Food':
    //      result = TAX_PERISHABLES;
    //      break;
    // }
    // return result;
    // }

// Tax calculation function
function calculateTax() {
    //TEST Government Compound taxes base num = 350
    var x = document.getElementById("totalAmount").value;
    var ITEM_COST = parseInt(x);
    var TAX_10 = ITEM_COST * 0.10; // 35
    var TAX_5 = ITEM_COST * 0.05; // 17.5
    var TAX_2 = ITEM_COST * 0.02; // 7
    var TAX_8 = ITEM_COST * 0.08; // 28
    var totalCompoundTax = TAX_10 + TAX_5 + TAX_2 + TAX_8;

    // Calculate tax based on category
    var feesFromDutiesCat = calcDutiesCatTax(e) * ITEM_COST;
    console.log(feesFromDutiesCat);
    // Total amount to be paid (Inclusive of all taxes)
    var totalAmountToBePaidInEc = feesFromDutiesCat + totalCompoundTax * (2.68);
    var totalAmountToBePaidInUsd = feesFromDutiesCat + totalCompoundTax;

    document.getElementById("totaltaxesXCD").innerHTML = totalAmountToBePaidInEc.toFixed(2) + ' XCD';
    document.getElementById("totaltaxesUSD").innerHTML = '$' + totalAmountToBePaidInUsd.toFixed(2);
}

// console.log(selValue);
// var calcDutiesCat = function (value) {
//  var result = "";
//  switch (value) {
//      case 'electronics':
//          result = TAX_ELECTRONICS;
//          break;
//      case 'Automobile':
//          result = TAX_AUTOMOBILES;
//          break;
//      case 'Food':
//          result = TAX_PERISHABLES;
//          break;
//  }
//  return result;
// }

// function calcDutiesCatTax(val) {
//      if (val === selValue) {
//          return TAX_ELECTRONICS;
//      } else if (val === selValue) {
//          return TAX_PERISHABLES;
//      } else {
//          return TAX_AUTOMOBILES;
//      }
//  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calcDutiesCatTax() just replace this function. i hope it's works for you.

```js
//Percentages based on duties category
const TAX_ELECTRONICS = 0.31 //31%
const TAX_AUTOMOBILES = 0.33 //33%
const TAX_PERISHABLES = 0.12 //12%

// Exhibit 1: Get and store value from select option
var selObj = document.getElementById("dutiesCategory");
var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;

// Check Option Value click handler
function getOption() {
 selectElement = document.querySelector('#dutiesCategory');
 output = selectElement.value;
 document.querySelector('.output').textContent = output;
}
var e = getOption();

// Exhibit 2: Test to see if we're still getting an option value
function tester() {
var f = $("#dutiesCategory").change(function() {
 var g = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
 //console.log(g);
});
}
tester();

// Important: I need to find a way to get the values from the select input and merge them with the calculateTax function.
function calcDutiesCatTax() {

if($("#dutiesCategory").val() == "electronics")
{
return TAX_ELECTRONICS;
}
else if($("#dutiesCategory").val() == "food")
{
return TAX_PERISHABLES;
}
else if($("#dutiesCategory").val() == "automobile")
{
return TAX_AUTOMOBILES;
}

};

 // function calcDutiesCatTax(val) {
 // var result = "";
 // switch (selValue === val) {
 //  case 'Electronics':
 //   result = TAX_ELECTRONICS;
 //   break;
 //  case 'Automobile':
 //   result = TAX_AUTOMOBILES;
 //   break;
 //  case 'Food':
 //   result = TAX_PERISHABLES;
 //   break;
 // }
 // return result;
 // }

// Tax calculation function
function calculateTax() {
debugger
 //TEST Government Compound taxes base num = 350
 var x = document.getElementById("totalAmount").value;
 var ITEM_COST = parseInt(x);
 var TAX_10 = ITEM_COST * 0.10; // 35
 var TAX_5 = ITEM_COST * 0.05; // 17.5
 var TAX_2 = ITEM_COST * 0.02; // 7
 var TAX_8 = ITEM_COST * 0.08; // 28
 var totalCompoundTax = TAX_10 + TAX_5 + TAX_2 + TAX_8;

 // Calculate tax based on category
 var feesFromDutiesCat = calcDutiesCatTax() * ITEM_COST;
 console.log(feesFromDutiesCat);
 // Total amount to be paid (Inclusive of all taxes)
 var totalAmountToBePaidInEc = feesFromDutiesCat + totalCompoundTax * (2.68);
 var totalAmountToBePaidInUsd = feesFromDutiesCat + totalCompoundTax;

 document.getElementById("totaltaxesXCD").innerHTML = totalAmountToBePaidInEc.toFixed(2) + ' XCD';
 document.getElementById("totaltaxesUSD").innerHTML = '$' + totalAmountToBePaidInUsd.toFixed(2);
}

// console.log(selValue);
// var calcDutiesCat = function (value) {
//  var result = "";
//  switch (value) {
//   case 'electronics':
//    result = TAX_ELECTRONICS;
//    break;
//   case 'Automobile':
//    result = TAX_AUTOMOBILES;
//    break;
//   case 'Food':
//    result = TAX_PERISHABLES;
//    break;
//  }
//  return result;
// }

// function calcDutiesCatTax(val) {
//   if (val === selValue) {
//    return TAX_ELECTRONICS;
//   } else if (val === selValue) {
//    return TAX_PERISHABLES;
//   } else {
//    return TAX_AUTOMOBILES;
//   }
//  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Anguilla Customs Duties Calculator</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.12/css/bootstrap-select.css" integrity="sha256-+oD8XVy0yTlpJi12d9AW34KibDEViR8XPho0d127HZA="
  crossorigin="anonymous" />
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="section mt-5">
   <div class="row justify-content-start text-center">
    <div class="col">
     <small class="text-muted">A N G U I L L A</small>
     <h1>Duties Calculator</h1>
     <p class="lead">Enter details to begin</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FORM -->
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
     <div class="col">
     <form name="dutiescalculator" id="dutiescalculator">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nameOfPerson">Your name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameOfPerson" aria-describedby="nameHelp">
    <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll need your name to create your receipt.</small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dutiesCategory">Duties Category</label>
    <select id="dutiesCategory" class="form-control selectpicker"  aria-describedby="dutiesHelp">
      <option name="electro" value="electronics" selected="selected">Electronics</option>
   <option name="automobile" value="automobile" >Automobile</option>
      <option name="food" value="food">Food</option>
    </select>
   <small id="dutiesHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is used to calculate your total tax amount.</small>
    <p class="mb-1 pb-1"> 
        The value of the option selected is:  
        <span class="output"></span> 
    </p> 
   <button class="btn mt-4 btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="getOption(); return false;"> 
        Check option 
    </button> 
  </div>


<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
  </div>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="totalAmount" aria-label="taxHelp">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
<small id="taxHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter the total amount of taxable items.</small>

  <button type="submit" value="click me" onclick="calculateTax(); return false;" class="btn mt-4 btn-primary">Calculate my taxes</button>
</form>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row pt-3">
    <div class="col">
      <b>Amount to be paid</b>
      <p class="mb-0"><small><b>IN XCD:</b></small></p>
      <div class="lead" id="totaltaxesXCD"></div>
      <p class="mb-0"><small><b>IN USD:</b></small></p>
      <div class="lead pt-0 mt-0" id="totaltaxesUSD"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.12/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```